# coding c# for the drop menu so that it doesn't cover the menu below it

Tags: c#, menu

I created a drop down menu in C# Winform, below the drop down menu there is another button. The button below it is covered when the drop down menu above it is clicked. how to solve it?
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq4FN.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAacC.jpg)

I've tried everything I can. but it's hard to deal with it because I'm a beginner in this field. I hope to find a way here.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, something else? We'd need to see your existing code in order to help you.

Comment: This is WinForms and i use timer tools

Comment: Please edit your question based on the new informations. No one want's to read all comments in order to help you.